# citeproc-lua prevent hyphenating the urls in references

Tags: luatex, urls, lua, pandoc-citeproc

I use [citeproc-lua](https://github.com/zepinglee/citeproc-lua) with texstudio in Windows 11. I have used `apa` csl style provided with the package [`citation-style-language`](https://www.ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.2575.1642887499.10251.ctan-ann@ctan.org) as example here, but I have to use `american-medical-association` csl style in my original report. I have installed the package `citation-style-language` with `tlmgr`. The problem is, when i have urls in my references, they get hyphenated, so they become useless. The urls aslo get rendered as normal text instead of typewriter font family in output, which is acceptable. I have provided the MWE. I want to prevent urls from getting hyphenated, instead i want just a linebreak for long URLs with `citeproc-lua`. I searched online but could not find an answer.

```
\documentclass[12pt,abstract = true,toc = flat,toc = bib]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{citation-style-language}
\cslsetup{style = apa}
\addbibresource{mylibrar.bib}
\begin{filecontents}{mylibrar.bib}
    @article{baillie_deliver_2021,
        title = {Deliver high levels of {SOx} reduction with {SOx}-reduction additive},
        url = "https://www.hydrocarbonprocessing.com/magazine/2021/september-2021/catalysts/deliver-high-levels-of-sox-reduction-with-sox-reduction-additive",
        journal = {Hydrocarbon Processing},
        author = {Baillie, C and Cooper, C},
        month = sep,
        year = {2021},
    }
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Is there a reason for not running `\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}` instead of `\usepackage{citation-style-language} \cslsetup{style = apa}`?

Comment: Running the `pdflatex`-`citeproc`-`pdflatex` cycle we can find in the `.bbl` that the URL is not wrapper in the `\url` macro. This usually makes for bad line breaks. It might be worth brining this up at https://github.com/zepinglee/citeproc-lua/issues as I don't think it make sense to try and change the `csl` file to include the `\url` macro. (While you are at it, you may also want to ask about the "original work published" which looks odd.)

Comment: @Mico, I don't use `apa` style, i use `csl` styles, which are not avaiable in `bibtex` or `biblatex`. Here i have only used `apa` as an example

Comment: @moewe, I have opened [the issue](https://github.com/zepinglee/citeproc-lua/issues/12#issue-1160650608).

Comment: @moewe, the fix is available, but i do not know how to apply it! I only know how to install `citation-style-language` package with `tlmgr`. Can you please tell me how to apply [the fix](https://github.com/zepinglee/citeproc-lua/issues/12#issuecomment-1061701316)?

Comment: The fix seems to be available only in a development branch on GitHub. Generally I would recommend to wait until the fix has hit CTAN and thus lands in your TeX Live (and thus gets updated with `tlmgr`). If you want to test the fix now, it might be worth a try to ask the developer how that is best done.